# ¿Cómo desactivar el 'draggable' de Google Map en navegación Android con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

Necesito setear a false el draggable en navegación móvil android.

Este es mi código

```
function setMap(mapElement)
{
    var street = mapElement.dataset.ss;
    var city = mapElement.dataset.cc;
    var province = mapElement.dataset.pp;
    var q = encodeURIComponent(street+' '+city+' '+province);
    var k = "AIzaasdfasdfasadasdadadadd";
    $('#map').attr('src','https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key='+k+'&q='+q);
    $('#map').draggable($(document).width() > 340 ? 'enable' : 'disable'); // no existe
}
```

Comment: haz intentado `window.ondragstart = function() { return false; } ` ?

Answer (score 1):

Cómo dicen en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3637086/1468942) del SO original:

```
myObject.draggable('destroy')
```

Ya que el `disable` se comporta de maneras *extrañas*.

Si así no te funciona y quieres una solución jQuery (como dice [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18797088/1468942)):

```
$("#draggable").draggable({ disabled: false });
```